# 404 Error getting JSON from Instagram Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, instagram

I am developing an application for a client which uses the Instagram graph to search for a specific hashtag. For this I use the following `JavaScript`:

```
let rawData, resuData;
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/dogs/?__a=1',
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
},
complete: function(data_response) {
    rawData = (data_response.responseText);
    resuData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    console.log(resuData);
},
error: function (error) {
console.log("Error!");
}
});
```

This gives me a `JSON` with the data I want.

The problem comes when I want to obtain the data from the "elbaresotracosa" hashtag (https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/elbaresotracosa/?__a=1) which shows me the message error **404** as shown in the following image.

[error 404 instagram graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EONhf.png)

But when I enter that URL from the browser itself, it shows me the `JSON` that I'm looking for.

[instagram graph JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tamg.png)

In the developer tools, from the Network tab, it says that the content-type is `"application/json"`

[content-type: application/json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX7XO.png)

Do any of you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have a **scraper** using the same endpoint and it stopped working yesterday.

I guess Instagram just blocked access to the tags explorer for unauthenticated requests.

If you're logged in you can see the hashtags, but open the same link in an incognito window and you won't (for some reason it still works for some hashtags like the #dogs one)

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue - any ideas on a work around?

Comment: I'm now using this as a workaround (you need an Instagram account though): https://github.com/jlobos/instagram-web-api